# Swift - TableViewController overwriting old data

Tags: ios, uitableview, button, swift

This is my situation. When I press button I move to the next screen, and at the same time it put my 2 parameters in TableView. It must working something like MasterDetailApplication and I strive to it. When I press button everything works fine. My question is, how could I do that, when I press the button, the data (2 parameters) are save in TableView, and when I do it again(press back button and again press Go button), a new data overwrites the old one. I want that a new data wasn't overwrite a old data, they must be above them. This is my code :

```
//Parameters.swift
import Foundation

struct Parameters {
    let toPass : String
    let toPass2: String
}

//SecondViewController

import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer = NSTimer()
    var counter = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var labelCounter: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        labelCounter.text = String(counter)
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1,target:self, selector: Selector("update"),userInfo: nil, repeats :true)

    }

    func update(){    
        labelCounter.text = String(++counter)
        if counter == 15 {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
        if (segue.identifier == "segueTest") { 
            var transfer = segue.destinationViewController as TableViewController
            transfer.toPass = labelCounter.text
            transfer.toPass2 = "\(formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))"
        }
    }
 }

//TableViewCOntroller   
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

    var toPass: String!
    var toPass2: String!
    var objects = [Parameters]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.objects = [Parameters(toPass: toPass2, toPass2: toPass)]
        // self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red :184.0, green: 219.0, blue: 243.0)
        //  self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        // tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.objects.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        var param : Parameters
        param = objects[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel.text = param.toPass
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = param.toPass2 + " sec"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post to github?

Comment: I can't I just need a tip how to solve my problem.